# Macbookで色々なアプリケーションを試す方法

Tags: macos

最近、WEBブラウザやエディタなど、色々とインストールし試しています。

その際に、通常の環境に都度そのままインストールし、使い勝手が悪ければアンインストールするという方法をとると、Macbookの環境が知らずに汚れてしまうのではないかと懸念しており、隔離環境のような何らかの閉鎖的な環境を作り、そこにインストールして色々と試した方が良いのかなと考えています。
自分なりに考えたところ以下の方法があるのかなと思いますが、デメリットが目立ち、躊躇しているところです。みなさんは様々なアプリケーション、ソフトウェアなどを試すときにどのようにしているのか教えていただければと思います。

1. Dockerを利用
   　　macOSに基づくイメージが存在していないと思われる。代わりにLinux系で試すのもありなのかなと思いますが、細かい点での違いがでそうで、どうなのかなと思っている。
2. ゲストアカウントを利用
   　　正直やり方のイメージは沸いていない。macbookのアカウント編集部分は、購入当初に色々と苦戦し、なんども管理者アカウントが消え、OSを再インストールしなおすという経験をしたので、ここら辺の設定を触ることに、ネガティブなイメージを持っている。
3. BootCamp?というのを使う
   　　詳しく理解しているわけではないが、少し前から非推奨？になっている？

ざっくりとした質問で恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macのアプリケーションの環境設定は、基本的にはwindowsのレジストリのような巨大な共有ファイルに自身の設定を追加していく形ではなく、

- `~/Library/Preferences/`下に、環境設定ファイルが`.plist`形式で作られます
- `~/Library/Application Support/`下に（必要であればアプリケーション名のディレクトリを作り、その下に）データーベース的なアプリケーション固有のデーター

が、作られます。
更に`App Store`からダウンロード。購入するアプリは、`sandboxing`という`~/Library/Containers/`下にアプリケーション専用のディレクトリーが作成され、環境設定もユーザーデーターもこの下に作られ、ユーザーの許可無しにはこのディレクトリーより外のファイルにはアクセス出来ない様にされて、システムへの汚染を極力避けるような仕組みで作られています（そうしないと審査が通らないのです）。

なので、アプリケーションを削除したときはこれらのディレクトリー下を探して、目的のアプリケーション名を含むファイルを削除すれば、ほとんどのアプリケーションは副作用を残さずに削除出来ます。

アプリケーションを削除するときに、上記ディレクトリーを検索して、関連ファイルや設定ファイルを削除する`App Delete`や、システム環境設定に追加する機能拡張で、ゴミ箱を監視し、アプリケーションが削除（ゴミ箱に入れられたとき）`AppDelete`の様に「関連ファイルを消すか？」を確認した上で削除してくれる`AppTrap`というシステム機能拡張もあります。

僕が知っているのはこの2つですが、上記のアプリケーション削除サポートアプリケーションを使ったり、手動でアプリケーション削除後に上記フォルダーを巡回して不要ファイルを探して削除することで、Macの環境はかなりクリーンに保たれると思います。

Comment: なるほど...ということは基本的に何かアプリケーションをインストールしても、上記のフォルダだけにデータがインストールされることで、極力環境が汚れないようになっているのですね。非常に勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

TimeMachineを使って、都度バックアップしてからアプリを試し、使いにくければインストール前まで復元して戻せばいいと思います。

[Time Machine で Mac をバックアップまたは復元する方法](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT201250)